# How to get value from html text fields created in a loop?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-5

For a school project we need to make a webshop, we have a database filled with products and their name/price/morestuff. With a foreach loop I have made a table:

```
<form action="sendStuff">
<table>
    @foreach (Product p in Model) 
    {
        <tr>
            <td><a href="ShowProduct?productName=@p.productName">@p.productName</a></td>
            <td>@p.price</td>
            <td><input id="@p.productName" type="number" name="p.productName" value="0"/></td>
       </tr>
    }
</table>
//this is where i want to submit the values to my controller, but how??
<input type="submit" value="Make Order Now">
</form>
```

Since the products come from a database and the amount of products in the database is not final, I cant just give them `id="something123"` because then all the inputs have the same id since i make them in a loop. That is why i choose to make the `id="@p.productName"`.

My question is how can i give my controller the needed info, in this case the value of the inputfields and also i need to know which value belongs to which row in the table(can make use of an index?)

I also tried putting them all in an arrayList but then i still can't figure out how to push it to the controller on the push of a button.

Let me know if you need any more code from my project or any details :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use strongly typed views that are bound to the model you are editing.

In your case you could use the Html.EditorFor(model => model.Products), which will reference a file named Products.cshtml in the Products/EditorTemplates folder.  This Products.cshtml will contain Html.TextBoxFor and other HtmlHelper functions to build your form for you list of products.  That the controller doesn't have to rely on you to manually create a list of products in the form view.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions(v=vs.118).aspx

**Update**

If you want to post a list of objects to your controller, then the method that you are posting to must accept that as a parameter.

```
public ActionResult EditProducts(List<Product> products) {}
```

So for your view, you will want to iterate over your collection in order to produce the proper HTTP Post array back to your controller

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.TextBox("product[" + @i + "].ID", Model[i].ID)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This is the manual way of creating an array to post back to your controller, what I mentioned previously will give that workload to the Razor view engine instead of you manually building these form lists.

Also it seems that your form tag does not have an action attribute so it is not posting the data to the proper url

Comment: I do not understand your suggestion. Also we already have a products.cshtml file so i don't know how that is gonna work. i simply want to post the values of the fields to the controller.

Comment: It should be `@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].productName) }`